# Notation: Should the product of two fractions have a dot between them?

Tags: notation

There seem to be two reasonable ways to express the product of two fractions with involved numerators and denominators. The first is:

$$\frac{K_M}{K_M^2+BR}\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_n s+\omega_n^2}$$

The second is with a dot such as LaTeX's `\cdot`:
$$\frac{K_M}{K_M^2+BR}\cdot\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_n s+\omega_n^2}$$

My apologies if this is off topic (it is a good fit for neither the LaTeX SE nor the Graphic Design SE). I have been unable to find guidance on the topic from a style manual. I welcome input from the community. Thank you!

Comment: It's the same thing. Either option is fine. Even if the first one is an abuse of notation, people abuse notations all the time.

Comment: Another common way is to put brackets around both the fractions. So something like $$\left ( \frac {23n} {n}\right ) \left ( \frac {3n} {n}\right )$$

Comment: Notation is ultimately about conveying an idea. Here, the idea is conveyed (in my opinion) equally clearly either way, so I don't think it matters too much

Comment: Usually not required, but sometimes, particular when the font is small, you might include the $\cdot.$ In particular, to distinguish $\frac12\cdot \frac34$ from $\frac{13}{24},$ which might look too similar to $\frac12\frac34.$

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. Yet another option is ${a\over b}\times{c\over d}$.

Comment: I prefer the dot because it makes it easier to read, and less likely to be mis-read. But it is not mandatory.